# Check a string list for Upper Case Letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I am trying to use the [isUpper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) built-in function to test a **string list** for Upper Case letters.

```
text = ['The', 'Big', 'Brown', 'Fox' ,'jumped', 'over', 'the','lazy','dog']

for x in text:
    if x.isupper():
        print(x)
```

However, there is no output for this. If the brackets are removed, there is some output but it is still incorrect.

```
for x in text:
    if x.isupper:
        print(x)
```

Output:

```
The
Big
Brown
Fox
jumped
over
the
lazy
dog
```

Comment: You need to check if any letter is upper-case in the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isupper` is a method so you need the bracket to call it. For the output, it is right. the method `isupper` is returning True if and only if all characters are uppercase. In your case, you should use `istitle()` method.

I hope it helps,

Answer (score 1):

`str.isupper()` checks whether all characters in the string is upper cased.
If you wanna go simple - just check if .lower() version of the string is different:

```py
for w in text:
 if w.lower() != w:
  print(w)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check if a string contains an upper-case letter, you can use:

```
print(*[x for x in text if not x.islower()])
```

---

```
The Big Brown Fox
```

[DEMO](https://trinket.io/python3/7022611637)